# What is the name of the default, preinstalled, PDF viewer on Ubuntu?

Tags: pdf

I've been looking for the name of the Ubuntu's PDF reader preinstalled app.
I just wanna a great PDF reader that support complementary mode for windows.

Thank you!

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evince (on my version, ubuntu GNOME 14.04, at least)

Answer (score 0):

Evince - Can be used for GNOME

Okular - Can be used for KDE

Notable PDF for chrome -found in chorme app store, can also be also used ( edit is not allowed here)